# How to enter first 100 character of 200 in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a field with varchar(100) in mysql, I want to store first 100 characters because my data length is 200 characters(ignore last 100 character).I doesn't want to change my source code. Which is possible in MS-Access and MS Server but I want to do this in mysql.

I am applying this in java with hibernate, means I am not writing insertion code for this. Here I am just using save() method and its throwing "Large data".

I have got Exception-

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'FBUrl' at row 1
>   `at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1527)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1065)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:58)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:195)
>   glb.chatmeter.exception.AdException: Could not Save Facebook page Data.`

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you ran an `INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (stringLongerThan100Chars)` where `field` is `VARCHAR(100)`?

Comment: Do you want it in pure SQL or the the programming language you use?

Comment: @jensgram that will usually work; however, it will result in an error if mySQL is in strict mode.

Comment: @Pekka, you're right: "If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a CHAR or VARCHAR column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated" ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html))

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: An hour after the below, the question was edited with a *substantial* change. This answer answered the question as it was originally, but doesn't address the edited version.

---

You can use [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Myfield) values (SUBSTRING('long string', 1, 100))
```

The `pos` parameter starts at `1` (oddly), and it's okay if the `len` parameter is larger than the length of what you're actually inserting.

Comment: MySQL `SUBSTRING()` specifies that strings start at position **1**, as opposed to 0 in most programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to trim inserts:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (SUBSTRING("your data...", 1, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT INSERT('your string', 0, 100, '');
```

[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it without changing the source code is to fiddle with the configuration of the MySQL server. More specifically, the `sql_mode` variable:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html

I believe you have to set `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`:

> For STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, MySQL
>   converts an invalid value to the
>   closest valid value for the column and
>   insert the adjusted value. If a value
>   is missing, MySQL inserts the implicit
>   default value for the column data
>   type. In either case, MySQL generates
>   a warning rather than an error and
>   continues processing the statement.
>   Implicit defaults are described in
>   Section 10.1.4, “Data Type Default
>   Values”.

However, it's important to note that this setting will affect many other things. The only reason I see not to change the source code is that you don't have access to it, and in such case you can probably just enlarge the DB column.